# Is it possible to use CMake find_package with a version with not only numbers?

Tags: cmake

Could it be possible to use CMake `find_package` with a version where there is something more than numbers, like `1.2.1-rc1`?

Every time that I try:

```
find_package(libfoo 1.2.1-rc1)
```

I got the error:

```
find_package called with invalid argument "1.2.1-rc1"
```

Would it be possible to pass that type of version to `find_package`?

Comment: The [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#version-selection) for `find_package()` designates that the format must be `major[.minor[.patch[.tweak]]]`. Did you maybe try `1.2.1.1`?

Comment: Yes, that works but I would like to put a letter at the end intead of a number.

Comment: "Could it be possible to use CMake `find_package` with a version where ..." - technically, it is possible. But it is not a CMake itself who checks versions compatibility. Instead, that compatibility is checked by the script `Findlibfoo.cmake` (MODULE mode of `find_package`) or `libfooVersion.cmake` (CONFIG mode). Unless this script can handle `-rc1` version component, using such component in `find_package` wouldn't get desired effect.